# What is causing my avocado tree rot on leaf

Tags: diseases, fertilizer, fungus, avocado

I’m a newbie to growing avocado tree. This guys been growing for afew months and has recently started getting light brown spots on one of its leafs. The other leafs look okay apart from one or two which has started to get very very small light green patches. I did some research and I’m thinking it’s some kind of fungal disease ??
I live in the uk so temperatures are pretty cold but the plant is still getting its 6hr sunlight and the house is warm so shouldn’t affect it. I heavenly drain the plants soil ever 4 weeks or so and I’m using lorbex specialist feed. Was thinking to start using coffee grounds as fertilisers aswell.

So recap 
•does anyone know the cause to my boys wilting 
•suggestion on how to fix it 
•would you recommend ye coffee fertiliser and how would you go about doing it